# Most efficient rails join call for this case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

My models are:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :votes
    belongs_to :user
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :link
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_secure_password

    has_many :links
    has_many :votes
end
```

I have a page where I list all the links in the system. For each link I want to display both the current sum of all the votes as well as whether or not the user making the request has voted on that particular link (and if so what that vote's value was). I want to do this in the most efficient manner.

Currently in order to return the links and sums of the votes I have this in my Link controller:

```
def index
    @links = Link.all(:joins => :votes, :select => "links.*, sum(votes.value) as votes_total", :group => "links.id")
end
```

Which works well and gives me all my information in a single call. So my question is, do I need to make a second query to return the vote (if it exists) for current_user or can I incorporate that into my first query somehow?

Additionally, perhaps I should set up some kind of sum_caching in the database but I'm not sure the best way to go about that either. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
@links = Link.
  joins(:votes). 
  select(
    "links.*, sum(votes.value) as votes_total, sum(case votes.user_id when #{current_user.id} then votes.value else 0 end) as current_vote", 
    :group => "links.id"
  )
```

That would give you the current user's vote value as `@links.first.current_vote`. Of course, if your system has votes with a value of zero, it doesn't distinguish between "current user voted 0 on this link" and "current user did not vote on this link". You could add yet another selected value (`sum(case votes.user_id when #{current_user.id} then 1 else 0 end) as current_vote_exists`) to handle that, I suppose.

Naturally, you want to be really careful when interpolating into SQL like this, and/or look up the SQL-sanitizing tools that come with ActiveRecord.